# function declared in my class is not showing in scope

Tags: c++, qt

in my .h:

```
class ImagePixmapItem: public QGraphicsPixmapItem
    {
    public:
    void setSize(qreal size);
    private:
    qreal size;
};
```

In my class file I now have two functions:

```
#include "imagepixmapitem.h"
#include <QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent>

ImagePixmapItem::ImagePixmapItem(const QPixmap &pixmap, QGraphicsItem *parentItem)
: QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap,parentItem)
    {
    setCacheMode(NoCache);
    }

ImagePixmapItem::~ImagePixmapItem()
    {
    }

void ImagePixmapItem::setSize(qreal size)
    {
    this->size = size;
    }
void wheelEvent ( QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent * event ){
    qreal size = 1.2;
    if (event->delta() < 0)
      size = 1.0 / size;
    setSize(size);
}
```

yet I am getting an error on setSize:

../IMViewer/imagepixmapitem.cpp:42: error: ‘setSize’ was not declared in this scope

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void wheelEvent ( QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent * event )
```

should say

```
void ImagePixmapItem::wheelEvent ( QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent * event )
```

and also add this to the .h

```
protected:
    void wheelEvent ( QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent * event );
```

Answer (score 1):

`wheelEvent` is a free function and thus cannot call the member function `ImagePixmapItem::setSize` without an instance of `ImagePixmapItem`.

Answer (score 0):

`void wheelEvent ( QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent * event )` is not a member of the `ImagePixmapItem` class whereas setSize() is. So to invoke setSize() you either need to make wheelEvent() as member of `ImagePixmapItem` class or pass an object of type `ImagePixmapItem` and then call `ImagePixmapItemObject.setSize( ... )`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `setSize` is not declared in the scope of function `wheelEvent`.  The function `setSize` is a member function of class `ImagePixmapItem`, so to call `setSize` you need an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

WheelEvent-function is missing ImagePixMapItem:: in front, what means that you actually need to override that function from QGraphicsPixmapItem
class

so there should be

in header:

```
protected:
    virtual void wheelEvent(QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent *event)
```

and in cpp

```
void ImagePixmapItem::wheelEvent(QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent *event)
```

Also you should notice that because you override the WheelEvent, it's implementation in QGraphicsItem-class is never called, so you should also call base classes implementation of the function:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem::wheenEvent(event);
```